# Extract list where string is contained inside a list inside the list

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have a list of objects. Let's call them meetings. Inside the meetings there is another list of objects. Let's call those participants. I want to return all meetings where a certain participant is in the list.

I want something like this:

```
meetings.Where(meeting => meeting.Participants.Name == "Test name").ToList();
```

Basically return a list of meetings, where the meeting has a participant with the name "Test name".

EDIT: I actually ended up using a MongoDB filter. Before I would just extract all the "meetings" (with a filter) and then use LINQ to filter the list. Might as well filter out the results on database level.. But this is good to know.

Comment: [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for `Any`?

```
var result = meetings
  .Where(meeting => meeting
     .Participants
     .Any(participant => participant.Name == "Test name"))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! That was easy haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ method `Any` and this one line of code :

```
var result = meetings.Where(m => m.Participants.Any(p => p.Name == "Test name")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you try the following:

```
 meetings.Where(m => m.Participants.Any(k => k.Name == "Test Name")).ToList();
```

Comment: `Where()` not `where()` :-P

Comment: I think `m.Name` should be `k.Name` as well.

Comment: Thanks all for the review and edited. Actually I am on mobile. Done in a hurry. I guess, it's ok now :D